# Twilio: Incoming Test Call to my Twilio Number

Tags: twilio

I want to the test the webhook that i setup for twilio requests.
Is there any way i can make a test call to trigger twilio to send the request without using a real phone number?
I can not use a real phone for testing because im sitting in Germany.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a tool like [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) to simulate the HTTP request Twilio makes to your endpoint.

You can find the specific parameters that a Twilio webhook will send in our [docs](http://twilio.com/docs)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i did already use Postman to simulate HTTP requests but i want to test the system with real data. Do you maybe have a real example request for me that i can then modify, to do further tests ?

Comment: Also do you know if it is a restriction of free accounts that i cannot receive a call from a different free account? Or if free accounts can not receive calls at all?